# Use generic interface as method argument in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

Lets say I have the following interface `Foo`

```
abstract public interface Foo {

    abstract String getFoo();
}
```

and two classes that extend `Foo`, `Bar1` and `Bar2`

```
public class Bar1 extends Foo{

    String foo = "foobar";
    public String getFoo(){
        return foo;
    }
}
//repeat for class Bar2
```

I want to create a translator class that had a method that a client can call, which takes any object thats extending Foo as an argument (like `Bar1` or `Bar2` and translate the string to some other string. I did some digging and feel like generics are going to be the best way to do so, however I'm unable to properly modify either the method signature or the class signatures (not sure which, perhaps both?) to allow for this behavior.

```
public class TranslateBar{
    
//I have tried the following signatures, but clearly I'm missing something    

    public String translateBar(Foo<? extends Foo> pojo>{
        //return translated string
    }
    
    /*
    I read that Object is the supertype for all Java classes, so I thought maybe having it 
    take an Object in the parameters and then doing the wildcard would work, but no luck
    */

    public String translateBar(Object<? extends Foo> pojo>{
        //return translated string
    }
```

In all cases, it gives me an error in the generic saying `Type 'java.lang.Object'(or Foo) does not have type parameters`. The two options it gives me to fix are `create a field for pojo` which still doesn't solve the `<? extends Points2>` error.

How can I get my `translateBar` method to allow the client to pass any subclass of `Foo`?

Comment: What exactly would change in `Foo` and `Bar1`/`Bar2` when introducing the generic parameter? As is, you could just pass any `Foo` and, e.g., process it through a fitting handler, which you can register for a certain implementation fo `Foo` (although one must be careful with subclassing to select the "most specific" handler or only allow exact type matches).

Comment: No need for generics here, just basic polymophism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, a method that accepts a certain type, say `Foo`, will accept also any sub-type of `Foo`. There's no need to use generics in such case.

Here's how your code should look like:

```
public interface Foo {
    String getFoo();
}

public class Bar1 implements Foo {
    final String foo = "foobar";
    @Override
    public String getFoo(){
        return foo;
    }
}

public class TranslateBar {
    public String translateBar(Foo pojo) {
        //return translated string
    }
}
```

Now you can call `translateBar` with any implementation of `Foo` including `Bar1`:

```
new TranslateBar().translateBar(new Bar1());
```

You would use generic for different cases... for example, where the type returned by the `getFoo` method depended on the implementation.

```
// the type T is generic and depends on the implementation
public interface Foo<T> {
    T getFoo();
}

public class Bar1 implements Foo<String> {
    final String foo = "foobar";
    @Override
    public String getFoo(){
        return foo;
    }
}

public class TranslateBar {
    public String translateBar(Foo<?> pojo) {
        //return translated string
    }
}
```

Comment: As a follow up then, when might I want to use generics? If polymorphism is sufficient and any bar will work so long as it's a subclass of Foo, I don't get the point of generics in methods. Do they work the other way around?

Comment: The importance of generics will make sense to you when you come across a problem where you need it. It's are rarely used in a method like in this example unless bounded by a known type, otherwise the method couldn't do anything with the argument type-safely. Generics are extremely important for container types (e.g. List<String>, Set<Integer>...), as an example of a common problem it solves.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you don't need to use generics as the basic polymorphism will be sufficient

```
 public String translateBar(Foo pojo){
    //return translated string
}
```

And this will solve the issue if you just want to call the `getFoo()`

Comment: Using raw types is never a good idea, at minimum you would need to use `Foo<?>`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there is no raw type involved. The wording is a little bit unlucky. The second code-block assumes that no generics exist.